# How to fix bad-precaching-response (sw - worksbox)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

every time I get error - Uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: bad-precaching-response :: [{"url"
this error occurs both when logging into the site and when switching between pages, and sometimes the screen becomes just white until you clear the cache and log in again. Tell me what I'm doing wrong in the settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMQXo.png)

my SW file look like:

```html
import { setCacheNameDetails } from 'workbox-core';
import { precacheAndRoute, matchPrecache } from 'workbox-precaching';

import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import {
  CacheFirst,
  NetworkFirst,
  StaleWhileRevalidate,
} from 'workbox-strategies';
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from 'workbox-cacheable-response';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';

setCacheNameDetails({
  prefix: 'app',
});

// @ts-ignore
const manifest = self.__WB_MANIFEST || [];

if (manifest) {
  precacheAndRoute(manifest);
}

registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => request.mode === 'navigate',
  async ({ request }) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(request);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      const cacheResponse = await matchPrecache('/index.html');

      if (cacheResponse) {
        return cacheResponse;
      }

      return Response.error();
    }
  },
);

registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/api/'),
  new NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: 'api',
    networkTimeoutSeconds: 7,
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({
        statuses: [200],
      }),
    ],
  }),
);

registerRoute(
  ({ request }) =>
    request.destination === 'style' ||
    request.destination === 'script' ||
    request.destination === 'worker',
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'assets',
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({
        statuses: [200],
      }),
    ],
  }),
);

registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => request.destination === 'image',
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({
        statuses: [200],
      }),
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 7 Days
      }),
    ],
  }),
);
```

webpack plagin what generate sw file:

```html
    new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
      mode: 'production',
      swSrc: path.resolve(appPath, 'sw.ts'),
      exclude: [
        /\.htaccess$/,
        /manifest$/,
        /LICENSE$/,
        /\.gz$/,
        /\.br$/,
        /\.png$/,
        /\.jpg$/,
        /\.jpeg$/,
      ],
    }),
  ],
```

workbox version 5.0.0